# Where to get database error information in Android SQLite (e.g. failed insert due to violation of not null)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception

I just realized that one of my database insert() commands failed due to violation of a not null constraint - I just filled no data into this field.

Problem is, it took me ages to find out why this insert returned -1, because I could not find an error or Exception anywhere.

I'd expect, and I guess for more complex databases and query, it's totally important, to have somewhere some information from the database what's really going on that makes the DB access fail, but I could not find any information on this anywhere.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found that one can use insertOrThrow() instead of insert, at least you get an exception when, something goes wrong, saying android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed - even though I actually would wish/expect it would be even clearer and tell me which column has an error or so, but maybe I'm too demanding about SQLIte's feaures here.

Comment: If you debug and step into the insert can you not see exactly which column is throwing the exception?  That's not a statement of fact masked in sarcasm.  It is, in fact, a question as I've never tried.

Comment: @BillMote LogCat will display what the values you attempted to insert were and that an FK constraint failed; but it doesn't indicate which column was problematic.

Comment: Hi Henning, I have the same problem, I even tried InsertorThrow() but neither get I any exception, nor anything about SQLitedatabase in Logchat or any string containing SQL at all in my Logchat! but I get -1 on some items when inserting. I am not a pro developer, do you know how I can possibly find the reason?

Comment: HI @AbedNaseri - I didn't do more Android development for a long time now, sorry, I have no idea what you could do with current Android SDK and stuff.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked in LogCat?  It's usually pretty verbose about what's going on to include what's going wrong.

Comment: I dOn#t see any useful info in logCat

Comment: It simply states that there is a foreign key constraint.  It doesn't tell you WHICH foreign key constraint is the issue.  The fact that more people are not annoyed about this just shows how many people don't bother with database integrity.