# Error inserting records in SQLite DB

Tags: android, sqlite

in the following lines i create an image path and store that pth in sqqlite DB:

```
private void commitToDB() {
    imgTitle = "img";
    GenerateRandom gr = new GenerateRandom();
    imgTitle +=gr.getRand()+".jpeg";

    db = mpoh.getWritableDatabase();
    cv = new ContentValues();
    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(dir,"/DCIM/"+imgTitle);

    cv.put(imgName, imgTitle);
    cv.put(path,file.getAbsolutePath());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),imgTitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        long newID = db.insert("MPData", null, cv);

        if (newID == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error Commiting Record(s)",  
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Commited Successfully",  
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
```

and my SQLite DB looks like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + MP_TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " name TEXT, " +
            " lat REAL, " +
            " lng REAL, " +
            " date TEXT, " +
            " time TEXT, " +
            " path TEXT, " +
            " imgName TEXT " +
            ");" );
}
```

my problem is that, i receive "Error Commiting Record(s)" because of newID= -1

```
        long newID = db.insert("MPData", null, cv);
        if (newID == -1)
```

Also to note that, an instance of the DB is instantiated inside onCreate.

any suggestion to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: cv.put(imgName, imgTitle);
    cv.put(path,file.getAbsolutePath());
What is the value of imgName and path ?

Comment: cv.put(path,""+file.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: i fuond out how to solve my problem...am i allowed to post an answer to my question...maybe my soulion would be helpful to others!!!

Answer (score 0):

you need to get your error message, (as apposed to just -1)

see "insertOrThrow" here: [Where to get database error information in Android SQLite (e.g. failed insert due to violation of not null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390102/where-to-get-database-error-information-in-android-sqlite-e-g-failed-insert-du)

That way at least you can drill down on the problem.

Comment: there is no error messages exceot that one i display in the Toast as posted above

Comment: error, as in from sqlite - or check logcat to see if there is any sql-related errors. You could have a syntax error and you wouldn't know